# SQLite - alter a table's column type?

Tags: sqlite, sqlitemanager

I am starting a project involving a small database and I am considering to use SQLite. 
If I create a table and I defined one of the columns as text, but all the values stored are integers - is there a way to change the data type of a column? I am using SQLite Manager and I can't find a function that allows me to do that. Can I do it using a SQL command, or is it a restriction of SQLite?
Probably, even with this restriction, one can find some way around and create a new table with the required column types and then import data into it.

Regards,
Nick

Comment: there is no straight way to use `alter table` to change column type in SqLite http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html. What you can do is rename the table, create a new table with new structure and copy data to the new one.

Comment: +1 great question , that is why i dont use sqllite due to the limitations of its functionalities.

Comment: Somebody gave another answer and he deleted it soon after that. It was just the answer I was looking for. With SQLite Manager, I can select the table, view its structure and right click on the column name and choose "Edit". I can change the data type, but I get the warning this is a potentially dangerous operation - as long as we backup the table or the database, I don't see it as a great risk.

Comment: I did saw that , but not sure if it will work

Comment: NullSoulException - I tried it and it works - at least for a simple table with only a few rows.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

SQLite does not fully support ALTER TABLE statements. The only thing you can do is  rename a table and/or add columns. If you want to rename a column, your best option is to create a new table with the  new columns datatype/names, and to drop the old table in order to rename the new one.

Lets say, you have a table and need to rename "field-1" to "field-2":
First ==>> rename the old table:

```
    ALTER TABLE original RENAME TO tmp;
```

Now create the new table based on the old table but with the updated column name:
==>> create a table with the updated columns

```
    CREATE TABLE original(
    field_a INT
   , field_b INT
    );
```

Then copy the contents across from the original table.

```
   INSERT INTO origignal(field_a, field_b)
   SELECT field_a, field_b
   FROM tmp;
```

Lastly, drop the old table.

```
   DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Comment: Also, do this all in one transaction.

Comment: You can do it in the other order: create new table with temporary name, copy everything to new table, then drop old table and rename new table to its original name.  Then you only need a short-lived transaction around the drop-rename actions at the end instead of a long transaction around everything.

Comment: This is incorrect order. Look at this! https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no "quick" way to do this with SQLite. Not like you can with MySQL. You will have to drop the table, then re-add it.

Another thing to keep in mind is that SQLite is pretty flexible about the type of data that you can put into each section. Here is a link that describes the datatypes, and how they work: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Another option might be to use MySQL if the feature you are speaking of is a big deal to you. It's still free and is great for small projects.

Comment: Thank you Blaine. They've done a nice thing with the dynamic data types, rather than constraining a value to a static type, they match the container to the data you want to store. I probably don't need to change the data type too often, only during development. I was taking it for granted and I was surprised it't not so straightforward.

Comment: I know what you mean. I had to do the same thing, but learned the hard way. Good luck with it.

Answer (score -1):

Alter table in SqliteManger

Steps

1. Open database in sqlite manage
2. double click on table name
3. will popup alter window.

Answer (score -2):

With sqllite manager 3.5 double clic on the table that you need to modify