# SQLITE - Setting default value on INSERT

Tags: sqlite, replace, insert, default, exists

I need to make a statement that adds an user to my SQLite database if it doesn't exist, otherwise update its values and add 1 to his previous totalMessages.
So far I wrote this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (id, username, first, last, totalMessages) values (
'hisID',
'hisName',
'hisFirst',
'hisLast',
(SELECT totalMessages FROM users WHERE id = 'hisID') +1);
```

It works fine when the user already exists, but when it doesn't, the value of totalMessages is set to NULL, and I need it to be 0.

This is my users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users  (
id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(255), 
first VARCHAR(255),
last VARCHAR(255),
totalMessages INTEGER)
```

Can anybody tell me how to do it, please?

**UPDATE:** I tried using "DEFAULT '0'" and "DEFAULT 0" as Scott suggested, but it is still saving totalMessages as NULL.

You can see it and test is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4e650/1).

Comment: Why does this need to be a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your table definition should include the default for the `totalMessages` column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users  (
...
totalMessages INTEGER DEFAULT '0')
```

SQLite doesn't allow for altering columns when modifying the table, however there are some strategies to do this manually, which have been documented at: "[SQLite Modify Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685885/sqlite-modify-column)" and "[SQLite - alter a table's column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21199398/sqlite-alter-a-tables-column-type)"

Comment: I know SQLite isn't strict about the data it is given, so I'm fairly certain the default I listed as `'0'` will work, however I'm not sure if it could have just been `0` and if that would be better.

Comment: totalMessages is still NULL doing that, maybe because the returned value from the SELECT is null, I'm not sure

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution to my problem that may not be the best but it works.

```
REPLACE INTO users (id, username, first, last, totalMessages) values (
'hisID',
'hisName',
'hisFirst',
'hisLast',
CASE WHEN (SELECT totalMessages FROM users WHERE id = 'hisID') IS NULL THEN
  0
ELSE
  (SELECT totalMessages FROM users WHERE id = 'hisID') +1
END);
```

If anybody has a better solution please answer.